# Dimitre Novatchev's XPath visualizer help

Tags: firefox, xpath, visualizer

I want to try what looks like a really cool tool. I've dl'd the FF version from http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html.

I open XPathMain.htm in FireFox, Browse to the provided `test1.xml` file, click Process File, with the default `//*` in the XPath window.  In FF, I get this:

> [Exception... "Access to restricted
>   URI denied" code: "1012" nsresult:
>   "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"
>   location:
>   "file:///Users/doug/Dev/XPV-FF/XPathMain.htm
>   Line: 43"]

I also opened it in Safari, followed the above, and *nothing* happened, when I clicked Process File.

Once I get it working, what am I expecting to see?  I assume I will see the xml file in the big window with selected nodes highlighted?

I'm on OS X 10.6.6 and FF 3.5.16. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error also and after a bit of trial and error, I resolved the problem by placing my .xml file in the same directory as **XPathMain.htm**. It then immediately rendered in the lower window after selecting the *Process File* button.

Moving the **authors.xml** file outside the `XPV-FF/` generates the same error. Perhaps this is the same origin policy type security?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what could be an issue-- **I cannot reproduce the reported problem**.

Just downloaded and installed FF 4, opened [**file:///C:/Temp/XPV-FF/XPathMain.htm**](http://file:///C:/Temp/XPV-FF/XPathMain.htm)

and then specified:

C:\Temp\XPV-FF\authors.xml

**The XPV works as expected**.

Please, try to work with the file `authors.xml` that comes with the XPV and is in the same folder as the XPV starting page. If you can work with this file, this definitely means that there is a permission problem with the file that has the reported issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, and moving to the same directory fixed it. Even so, I received the two other errors even with authors.xml: XPath error, and TypeError: xsltProcessor.transformDocument is not a function. So far I have been unable to open any document with your visualizer, but I'll be looking into it.

Comment: @PédeLeão, I confirm the issue -- something obviously changed in the new versions of FF. Experts are welcomr to propose a corresponding fix. Till then, please, use the IE version.