# How to work with Xpath visualiser

Tags: xpath

I have downloaded XPath Visualizer Version 1.4 folder from
http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html  link compatable to IE .I'm currently using Internet Explorer 8,then opened  'XPathMain.htm' file from the folder that is downloaded and tried to browse 'authors.xml' and gave  xpath expression as //* and hit 'process file' button but i didnt get any output. Do i need to configure anything in my browser or include any jscript as such. There is nothing as such mentioned in 'read me' file.

Comment: The project is last updated 10 years ago, you sure it is compatible with IE8?

Comment: I happen to be the author of the XPV and I haven't ever had any such problem reported by even a single user (out of the many thousands who have downloaded XPV). AFAIK, whenever you load the tool there would be a warning message asking you ("Allow blocked content") to click on the "yes" button, because XPV uses some Javascript extension functions internally. You must click "yes" or otherwise you'll get the currently reported behavior. This could also be a permission problem, if you don't have access granted to the folder where XPV resides or the file location for the file you want to load.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev your Xpath Visualiser doesn't work with latest FF or IE... file is put in a desktop and it shows "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied" Fresh install of OS and Browser (VM) and when using IE it shows TypeError: Unable to get property 'load' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @Andrew, I have been using the XPV all these years with all versions of IE since 2000, and it is still working on IE11 -- just checked. The version for FF was a one-time work and I haven't used it with consequent FF versions, because I am not an FF user. I remember once a SO user (@flask I think, proposed a fix for a later FF version -- and this can still be found at SO somewhere). So, I cannot reproduce your experience using IE -- probably you are trying to access forbidden xml file (you don't have the necessary permissions)

Comment: @Andrew: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586210/dimitre-novatchevs-xpath-visualizer-help

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev i am using fresh install of OS (WIN7) and IE 11 version. I am trying to open your supplied test files in the xml-testcases folder and I am geting that error. Its your files, in your created directory. I have enabled all security protections in IE. Doesn't work. Probably doesn't work for many other users, but they just don't say anything and do not use it at all. You have something different on your computer.

Comment: @Andrew, I can reproduce the problem when running the downloaded XPV. The one I am running locally on my computer (not downloaded from Internet) runs successfully. It displays a Warning: "Internet Explorer restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls" and allows me to click on a "Allow blocked content" button". In the case of the downloaded XPV, no such dialog is displayed. This is probably a tightening of security in the latest IE version. I suspect that there are IE options that could be set to allow the XPV to produce this dialog and to execute as intended.

Comment: @Andrew, There is a newer version of the XPV, which is not browser-based and understands XPath 2 (in addition to XPath 1), but requires .NET (which is true by default on windows systems). It can be downloaded here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/files/XPath%20Visualizer%202/ . I encourage everyone, who needs a XPath visualizer, both for XPath 2.0 and XPath 1.0 to try the XPath Visualizer 2.

Comment: @Andrew, This problem **can** be avoided if one adds temporarily https://www.huttar.net as a trusted site and then download XPV. After the download is performed and you have verified that XPV is working (You will still have to click the "Allow blocked content" button on each start of XPV), you can remove the site from the list of trusted sites.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev i tried the new XPV based on .NET and it works properly. Should I use it or should i try to hack the browser based version somehow and make it work? Or they are equal or maybe .NET version is better?

Comment: @Andrew, In a previous comment I described how you can download XPV (for XPath 1.0) and run it without a problem. You surely can do this. As for the XPV2 (for XPath 2.0) (.NET based), you can also use it. These two different versions of the XPV are ... *different*. The XPV 2 is necessary and perfect if you want to work with XPath 2.0. You can also feed it with XPath 1.0 expressions and this is OK. If you are restricted to only XPath 1.0 and feed the XPV2 with an expression that you think is XPath 1.0, but it really is XPath 2.0 and will raise an error with XPath 1.0 then XPV2 will not warn you

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Xpath Explorer](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=xpe%20jar&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGkQjBAwAg&url=http://sourceforge.net/projects/xpe/files/xpe/20030304/xpe.jar/download&ei=f4fhT8K1H-2RiQeQ6oWmDw&usg=AFQjCNEpvNO2otCYFGM0Pw6mXD0qKEFrFg)
Also check [this site](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) for online XPATH evaluator.

If have budget, go for [XML SPY](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xpath-analyzer.html).